# Retrieve numbers before/after sign change in [Double]

Tags: arrays, swift

I have a `[Double]` with values like `[60, 21, -18, -57, -95, -67, -29, 8, 45, 82]`.

Is there a quick way with Swift to retrieve the numbers before the next element is a number with the opposite sign?

With the example data set, the returned values should be: `-18, 21` and `-29, 8` or their equivalent indexes in the array.

I know I can use `.filter()` to compare values and sort them to retrieve the max and min of the entire set, but retrieving multiple ranges dependent on sign changes (can be more than two) is a bit more confusing for me.

Comment: You surely tried _something_. SO is not a free code writing website. Without showing at least some (research) effort, you're highly unlikely to receive an answer here.

Comment: Basically you want one positive and one negative closest to Zero. Right?

Comment: And regarding quick way of doing it. There isn’t such you might need to write it yourself.

Comment: I have updated my question with a better explanation of what I am trying to accomplish. My apologies for the vagueness initially.

Comment: @LeoDabus You've been on this site more than long enough that you should know reposting closed questions isn't appropriate.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson It is very clear what OP is trying to accomplish

Comment: @LeoDabus He took away my posting privileges for this?? Yet in his private feedback told me to edit or repost.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Out of a list of negative numbers, there can be a 'highest' negative number. This simply means the number out of the list of negative numbers that is closest to zero on a number line. Similarly, after zero on a number line, there are positive numbers. In a list of positive numbers, there can be a 'lowest' positive number which simply means it is the number from the list that is closest to zero. A sign change with in this context refers to a number passing the zero mark on a number line. I can add this background info to my question.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson If you're confused about that, then simply ask me about it in the comments and I can clarify by editing my question. I don't understand why taking my posting privileges away was deemed necessary.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I would appreciate your vote now and get this question reopened and hopefully my privileges restored.

Comment: Looking at your last few questions you have not included your own attempt in any of them, maybe this is something for you to ponder to avoid this situation again.

Comment: Also curious why not a simple `for` loop would be the quickest solution here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```swift
([60, 21, -18, -57, -95, -67, -29, 8, 45, 82] as [Double])
  .consecutivePairs
  .filter { $0.sign != $1.sign }
```

```swift
public extension Sequence {
  /// Each element of the sequence, paired with the element after.
  var consecutivePairs: Zip2Sequence<Self, DropFirstSequence<Self>> {
    zip(self, dropFirst())
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this:

```
let highestNegative = values.filter { $0 < 0 }.max()
let lowestPositive = values.filter { $0 > 0 }.min()
```

Both will be optional values. 0 will be ignored, but you can include it by modifying one of the operators.

Comment: I have updated my question with a better explanation of what I am trying to accomplish. My apologies for the vagueness initially.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to check if the last value is greater than zero and the current is less than zero, if true add the range to the results. Just make sure you add the lower value as the lower bound and the upper value as the upper bound:

```
let values: [Double] = [60, 21, -18, -57, -95, -67, -29, 8, 45, 82]

var last = values.last ?? 0
let ranges = values.dropFirst().compactMap { value -> ClosedRange<Double>? in
    defer { last = value }
    return last > 0 && value < 0 || last < 0 && value > 0 ? min(last,value)...max(last,value) : nil
}
print(ranges)  // [ClosedRange(-18.0...21.0), ClosedRange(-29.0...8.0)]
```